# Application Logs can not be forward though Diagnostic setting

Tags: logging, azure-functions, diagnostics

I have a azure function app, and i want to forward the application log to storage account for the future analysis & monitoring. However, the metrics are forwarded successfully, but the application log can not be seen, also we configured a event hub as another destination, but still, only the metrics can be seen, not the application logs.

The application log should be seen in Blob Storage

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the logs in azure storage account using this method.
I have create a function app with timer trigger function `timer_trigger`.

[image]

You can do the settings in either **Function App** OR **Application Insights**.

I have performed action in **Application insights**.

- Open Application Insights of the Function App.
- Go to **Monitoring -> Diagnostic settings -> add diagnostic setting**
  [image]
- create a Diagnostic setting and select `all logs` and select `Archieve to storage account` and **Save** it.
  [image]
- After some time, the logs will start to save in storage account in blob with name `insights-logs-<category name>`.

> **Note:- sometimes it takes time to generate logs through diagnostic settings.**

When you create Diagnostic Setting in **Function App ** only two option will be available. logs will be saved in blob name with same `insights-logs-<category name>` and `Providers` show as `Microsoft.web` as shown below:

[image]

[image]

**`Output`:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]